# Query from different classes

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

i am using Parse platform as backend, and i have **Posts** and **Media** classes.
each (img, file, ....) in Parse object inside **Media** class, and each one have column with pointer to Post object from Posts class.

i am trying to get all posts with media for each post, how i can do it with one query?

```
var Posts = Parse.Object.extend("posts");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Posts);
    var newObject = [];
    query.find().then(function(data){

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var item = data[i].toJSON();
            var newData = {};
            newData.objectId = item.objectId;
            newData.user = {
                userId: item.user.objectId,
                fullName: item.user.fullName,
                picture: item.user.imageUrl,
                userName: item.user.userName,
            };
            newData.date = item.createdAt;
            newData.hasImages = item.hasImages;
            newData.postBody = item.postBody;
            if(item.hasImages){
                var Media = Parse.Object.extend("media");
                var mediaQuery = new Parse.Query(Media);
                mediaQuery.limit(10);
                mediaQuery.descending("createdAt");
                mediaQuery.matches("post", item.objectId);
                mediaQuery.find().then(function(data){
                    newData.images = data;
                });
            }
            newObject.push(newData);
        }
        console.log(newObject);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach will be to have one to many relationship between the Post of the Media so each **Post** contains multiple **Media** objects and then you can use the following code in order to get all posts with all medias under it..

```js
var Posts = Parse.Object.extend("posts");
var query = new Parse.Query(Posts);

// add some coditions to the Posts query here if needed

query.include("media");  // include the media relation (0..n) 

// if you want to fetch only posts that have media under it you can use the following line of code
query.exists("media"); // make sure that only posts with media will be populated

query.find().then(function(posts){
  
  // here you have the list of posts
  // in order to access property of a post you can use the following code:
  
  for (var i=0;i < posts.length;i++){
    var post = posts[i];
    var postMedia = post.get("media"); // get all media objects in a specific post
    //..
  }
  
},function(error){
  // error 
});
```

You can read more about Parse relations in [here](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#relations)

Comment: Thanks Ran, the response return media feild like this "media": {"__type": "Relation","className": "media"}
how i can get the content inside the media?

Comment: In your media file you have the media URL (in a string). Take this string create NSURL out of it and then fetch the data either by NSURLConnection or via library (e.g. AFNetwork, Almofire etc.)